# Are LBW rules different in different formats of cricket?

Tags: rules, cricket

I have always seen reviews checking for `Pitched In Line` during *Tests* but not in *One Day Matches*. Is that my imagination or is it correct?

If they are indeed different, what are the differences?

Comment: Note that the LBW _law_ [(Law 36)](http://www.lords.org/laws-and-spirit/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-36-leg-before-wicket,62,ar.html) is exactly the same regardless of the format (and regardless of level, i.e. it's the same in club, domestic, and international cricket). The ICC [_playing conditions_](http://www.icc-cricket.com/rules_and_regulations.php) define how the review system operates in each format, which may affect the process of deciding whether a batsman is out or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference. The general rule:

1. If the ball pitches outside the leg-stump, the batsman can't be given out even if the ball goes on to hit the stumps.
2. If the ball pitches outside the off-stump and also hits the batsman outside the off-stump, then the batsman can't be given out. (This rule applies only if the batsman is playing a shot. If not, the batsman will be given out if the ball hits the stump).
3. If the ball hits the stumps and either pitches in line or outside off-stump, the batsman will be given out.

Now, in the reviews, three things are checked:

1. The ball pitches in line
2. Hits the wickets
3. Hits in line

From the general rule, you can see that even if the ball doesn't pitch in line, the batsman can still be given out based on rule 3. The three rules are checked and if they are satisfied, a batsman has to be given out. But, if 2 and 3 are satisfied, then a decision is made according to general rule 1 or 3.

Because of this, the reviews sometimes checks whether the ball is pitched in-line and sometimes they don't.

Last thing, the umpire can give any decision. Even if the review says the umpire is wrong, he can choose to stick to his decision.

Resources:

- [Law 36 (Leg Before Wicket)](http://www.lords.org/laws-and-spirit/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-36-leg-before-wicket,62,ar.html)
- [Umpire Decision Review System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umpire_Decision_Review_System)

Comment: @naveen I am absolutely sure that my last statement is right. For example- in 2010 World Cup, in the match of Ireland vs West Indies, Kevin O'Brien was given out by Umpire Ashoka Di Silva even after the review clearly showed that the ball hit the batsman outside the off-stamp.

Comment: The referral can be inconclusive in one of the three areas, meaning it's up to the umpire in the centre, so his original decision stands. If all three aspects clearly show the decision to be wrong it must be overruled. That's the point of the review system. Either side appeal. In the example you give from 2011 world cup, interpretation may have been wrong by the third umpire but the DRS wasn't overruled by Asoka de Silva.

Answer (score 6):

There are no differences in LBW rules between the three different formats of International Cricket. There are differences in how the umpire decision referral system (UDRS) is implemented in different countries, as it depends on what the TV company doing the broadcast has put in place. Possibly the differences you are seeing in referrals stems from that?

Comment: +1 makes sense. last ENG vs SA Test I saw an LBW overturned as it ain't pitched in line. And at last ODI between India and Srilanka I saw an LBW which didn't pitch on line being given out. Nobody was complaining.There was noe referral system anyway. But even the commentators were not talking anything about it.